# Is In-app purchase required for Huawei install referrer

Tags: react-native, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-iap

As per this [documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/install-referrer-0000001050198939) the way I can use Huawei install referrer in React Native is:

```
import {HMSInstallReferrer} from '@hmscore/react-native-hms-ads';
```

So install referrer is a part of the **hms-ads** package.

And of the 3 APIs in the documentation:

```
HMSInstallReferrer.startConnection(...,...)

HMSInstallReferrer.isReady()

HMSInstallReferrer.getReferrerDetails()
```

I can see that **startConnection()** is successful, but **isReady()** returns `result` as `false`.

After some research I found this [link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/config-agc-0000001050323366), where at the bottom it says:

```
Enabling Required Services

To use HUAWEI Ads, you need to enable the IAP service first and also set IAP parameters.
```

**Questions**

- Do we actually require In-App Purchase to be enabled to use simple
  install referrer?
- Won't that show as `"Contains in-app purchase"` on the app details
  page?
- For this service to enable there are too many things to set up as
  well, including merchant service etc.. which is too much for what we
  intend to build.